# ~/Desktop$ ls -la shows file on empty Desktop

Tags: osx

I'm just facing something strange when I run `ls` on Mac terminal on an empty Desktop:

My Desktop is absolutely clean and empty and those shown files are old, but familiar to me.
Can anyone please let me know why this is happening and how I can clean them?

Comment: All these files are hidden files

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Just post the text itself.

Comment: @M_dk Please don't [answer in the comments](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1333/18887). Please post as a proper answer instead.

Comment: @Sparhawk My comment was not a complete answer so I did not want to post it as such. Just wanted to give the guy a chance to delete his question before it was downvoted.

Comment: @M_dk IMO it was pretty close to a complete answer!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> My question is if that is something normal or those histories need to be cleaned and if yes, is there any way to do that? – Shahram 38 mins ago

It's normal to see these working/temporary/hidden files in windows and unix systems. Nothing extra ordinary large there to worry about. To delete use the `rm` shell command.

If you are short on disk space and want to find the large files download and try

- Windirstat on Windows systems or
- Disk Inventory X  on Mac
- Disk usage analyser on ubuntu

All scan the full file system and give graphical view of files and relative sizes.

Answer (score 1):

All the files you see in the output of the `ls -la` command are either

- dotfiles i.e. files beginning with a dot
- temporary Doc files, beginning with a tilde
- `Thumbs.db` file, which stores thumbnail icons for picture files

Neither of these are shown as icons in the Desktop graphical environment.

Run the command `ls -l` and you'll see what I mean. An useful reading is also `man ls`.

To delete them, run `rm -i .* ~*.docx Thumbs.db`

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.  My question is if that is something normal or those histories need to be cleaned and if yes, is there any way to do that?

Comment: You're welcome.  You should mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem.